# Find and delete list elements if matching a string

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a list of strings `stringlist = ["elementOne" , "elementTwo" , "elementThree"]` and I would like to search for elements that contain the `"Two"` string and delete that from the list so my list will become     `stringlist = ["elementOne" , "elementThree"]`

I managed to print them but don't really know how to delete completely from the list using `del` because i don't know the index or by using `stringlist.remove("elementTwo")` because I don't know the exact string of the element containing `"Two"`

My code so far:

```
for x in stringlist:
   if "Two" in x:
       print(x)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Normally when we perform list comprehension, we build a new list and assign it the same name as the old list. Though this will get the desired result, but this will not remove the old list in place.**

To make sure the reference remains the same, you must use this:

```
>>> stringlist[:] = [x for x in stringlist if "Two" not in x]
>>> stringlist
['elementOne', 'elementThree']
```

**Advantages:**
 Since it is assigning to a list slice, **it will replace the contents with the same Python list object**, so the reference remains the same, thereby preventing some bugs if it is being referenced elsewhere.

If you do this below, you will lose the reference to the original list.

```
>>> stringlist = [x for x in stringlist if "Two" not in x]
>>> stringlist
['elementOne', 'elementThree']
```

**So to preserve the reference, you build the list object and assign it the list slice.**

**To understand the subtle difference:**

Let us take a list `a1` containing some elements and assign list `a2` equal to `a1`.

```
>>> a1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a2 = a1
```

**Approach-1:**

```
>>> a1 = [x for x in a1 if x<2]

>>> a1
[1]
>>> a2
[1,2,3,4]
```

**Approach-2:**

```
>>> a1[:] = [x for x in a1 if x<2]

>>> a1
[1]
>>> a2
[1]
```

Approach-2 actually replaces the contents of the original `a1` list whereas Approach-1 does not.

Comment: How would you do this if you wanted to remove from a list instead of just a string. So if instead of wanting to remove "Two", you wanted to remove `remove_list = ["One", "Two"]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index when you iterate over your list (but Note that this is not a pythonic and safe way to modify your list while iterating over it):

```
>>> for i,x in enumerate(stringlist):
...    if "Two" in x:
...        print(x)
...        del stringlist[i]
... 
elementTwo
>>> stringlist
['elementOne', 'elementThree']
```

But as a more elegant and pythonic way you can use a list comprehension to preserve the elements that doesn't contains `Two` :

```
>>> stringlist = [i for i in stringlist if not "Two" in i]
>>> stringlist
['elementOne', 'elementThree']
```

Comment: Normally it's a bad idea to modify a list you're iterating over. Is it different in this case because you use enumerate()?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Good that you noted this, yeah actually its not safe to do that,and it doesn't make any difference that use `enumerate` or not!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this will help you

```
for i,x in enumerate(stringlist):
    if "Two" in x:
        del stringlist[i]
```

or

```
newList = []
for x in stringlist:
    if "Two" in x:
        continue
    else
        newList.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex,

```
import re

txt = ["SpainTwo", "StringOne"]
for i in txt:
    x = re.search(r"Two", i)
    if x:
        temp_list = temp_list + [x.string] if "temp_list" in locals() else [x.string] 

print(temp_list)
```

gives

```
['SpainTwo']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: "Two" not in x, ["elementOne" , "elementTwo" , "elementThree", "elementTwo"])))
```

Using lambda, if you are only looking to print.

Answer (score 0):

#### if you want to check for multiple string and delete if detected from list of string use following method

```
List_of_string = [ "easyapplyone", "appliedtwotime", "approachednone", "seenthreetime", "oneseen", "twoapproached"]

q = ["one","three"]

List_of_string[:] = [x for x in List_of_string if any(xs not in x for xs in q)]
print(List_of_string)

output:[ "approachednone", "seenthreetime"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Well this was pretty simple - sorry for all the trouble

```
for x in stringlist:
   if "Two" in x:
      stringlist.remove(x)
```

Comment: Don't do this. Modifying a list you're iterating over can produce weird results and errors

Comment: You are right, I've done that on a 2k element list and found that even if it removed most of elements containing the "Two" string I still find 4 elements that "somehow" skipped removal. Still trying to figure out the best solution. I'll keep you posted. Thank you!